# Asian characters display on the same webpage, some well and some not

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, display, browser

These [webpages at the University of Virginia Library website](https://cti.lib.virginia.edu/frame.htm), shows some Chinese characters. They are not displayed well.

The characters look like Chinese characters, but they are not as they should be (what's displayed are irrelevant and very seldom used characters). Look at the poem “001” on [this page here](https://cti.lib.virginia.edu/tangeng.html):

[image]

In Firefox, I've tried alternative languages but it doesn't resolve the display problem.

In Chrome, I've tried to use the extension Charset with different Chinese choices but still don't work out.

[image]

With Internet Explorer, tried the **Big 5** encoding, it also doesn't help.

I also tried to add a language Chinese Traditional (Hong Kong SAR) into the Windows 10 - after reboot, still no luck.

[image]

How can I have the characters displayed correctly?

Comment: It has to do with the font you are using. In Settings --> General --> Fonts and Colors, click on Advanced. In the Fonts dialog, select settings for Chinese, and check the font being used. You could copy the text into a word document and try other fonts to see if they display. It's also possible some kanji are non-standard and aren't included font sets.

Comment: @user3169, thank you for your comments! I've tried accordingly the Settings -->......... -->Advanced, for Chinese (itself, Hong Kong, Taiwan). also tried paste them into Word with different fonts, still no luck... :(

Comment: Seems like the actual characters aren't included in font sets. If you know what the incorrect characters should be, you might look them up here - [Unihan Database Lookup](https://unicode.org/charts/unihan.html). Also you might clarify exactly what the display issue is. Do you mean the two or three Simplified Chinese characters?

Comment: Also you can check in View Page Source in Firefox to see if any difference there.

Comment: @user3169, thank you for your comments again. The characters are Chinese characters, in an essence, but they are not as they should be (what's displayed are irrelevant and very seldom used characters). I used the Unihan Database Lookup but don't get them right. I've also used View Page Source in Firefox and it returns the same as displayed.

Comment: Thanks for updating the sample text. If you go to that page and select "This Frame --> View Frame Source" (not Page Source), you can see the text encoding is "Big5". Before Unicode, various encoding schemes were used to display foreign languages. Big5 was used for Chinese. Modern browsers try to encode as Unicode, which it comes out wrong. The bad news is that Firefox no longer supports selecting encodings (see [Text Encoding no longer available](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/text-encoding-no-longer-available-firefox-menu).

Comment: I don't use Chrome, but you need to be able to select the text encoding to "Big5" in some browser. Honestly, I haven't had to use such in over 10 years as they are obsolete due to the adoption of Unicode. I'm surprised these pages haven't been updated, though. Where did the corrected text you show come from? Seems they got it right.

Comment: @user3169, Thank you for your follow up. much appreciated! With Internet Explorer, I have tried to use the big 5 encoding, it doesn't help. I also tried to add a language Chinese Traditional (Hong Kong SAR) into the Windows 10 - after reboot, no luck. To get a correct text example, I read the English and trace it back the right Chinese piece.

Comment: If you haven't already, try This Frame --> Open Frame in New Tab, then set the encoding for that tab. The action is in the frame, not the main page.

Comment: @user3169, Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it and found the actual URL is, https://cti.lib.virginia.edu/tangeng.html. just unfortunately open it in a new tab still display the same.

Comment: And you set that new tab page to Big5? If display still NG, it is probably website/server issue. Though this page is so old... but maybe you can find a contact somewhere. Perhaps library main page [University of Virginia Library](https://library.virginia.edu)

Comment: @user3169, yes, set the new tab page to Big5... probably the last is the solution! :)

Comment: @user3169, your help is much appreciated. Would you consider to put down all the suggestions as an answer so that we can close this question?

Comment: Just to confirm what others say, if you look at the HTML in the page via “view source” the issue seems to be the page itself. Gibberish like this shows up in the raw HTML, `嚙緣嚙瘟嚙踝蕭嚙磕嚙諉`. The page itself is clearly old and was created in the olden days of [frame-based HTML](https://html.com/frames/) page design. Which means it truly is ancient. Best just contact the staff at that school an library and ask them to check the pages and see if they can be recovered. Otherwise, nobody on the browser side of the HTML can really do anything.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not an issue of fonts, as the characters are completely wrong. Rather it has to do with Character Encoding. These are systems where a numerical value in the html is assigned a specific character (using a lookup table).
Wrong encoding, wrong characters.

We don’t think of this much these days, due to the widespread adoption of Unicode, a standard encoding scheme that covers most languages’ character sets.

Before that, specific character sets were used to display non-Western language characters. In some cases, several systems exist for a single language.
Fortunately you can find the identifier in the source code. In your example, it’s:

`<meta charset="big5" />`

Big5 was one of the encodings commonly used to display Chinese characters. See:
[Big5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5)

Unfortunately, the major modern browsers don’t support non-Unicode encoding selection anymore.
If you can use an older version browser that can (keeping in mind security concerns when using them), then open the page (or frame in your case) and set the character encoding to Big-5.

If the page still doesn’t display properly, it’s likely the source html or web server has some issue or no longer supports this kind of action.

In your case, the page is old (1997) and probably no updates at all over time. I would recommend contacting the University Library to see if they can confirm/correct your issue.

Comment: The question states, BIG5 doesn’t help: “With Internet Explorer, tried the Big 5 encoding, it also doesn't help.”